# How $N$ qubits correspond to $2^N$ bits?

Tags: computation-models, quantum-computing

I read everywhere that $N$ qubits correspond to $2^N$ bits. Let's start with 1 qubit, which is commonly represented by $\alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$ where alpha and beta are complex numbers. This looks to me like infinite bits. How do they choose alpha and beta so that it becomes 2 bits?

Edit: Why is it commonly said that $N$ qubits correspond to $2^N$ bits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite what badly written pop-science explanations of quantum computation may tell you, a qubit is *not* two classical bits and $N$ qubits is *not* $2^N$ bits. Qubits are fundamentally different from bits, pairs of bits or anything else (except for a representation of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in binary to precision sufficient to classically simulate the computation to whatever precision is required).

As for *why* people talk about $N$ qubits being equivalent to $2^N$ bits, it's hard to say. To [paraphrase Tolstoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Karenina_principle), all correct explanations are alike but all incorrect explanations are incorrect in their own particular way. Perhaps it comes from the widespread mistaken belief that quantum computers somehow try all the options in parallel; perhaps it's a mistranslation of the fact that quantum computers offer exponential speedup over some classical algorithms. Scott Aaronson has [some thoughts along these lines](http://www.scottaaronson.com/talks/speedup.ppt):

> Fueling the belief that countless more quantum algorithms should exist (or that are not finding them is a failure), seems to be the idea that a quantum computer could just “try every possible answer in parallel”.
>
> But we’ve understood since the early 90s that that’s not how quantum algorithms work!  You need to choreograph an interference pattern, where the unwanted paths cancel
>
> The miracle, I’d say, is that this trick yields a speedup for any classical problems, not that it doesn’t work for more of them

Comment: Thanks. I see everywhere that  $N$ qubits correspond to $2^N$ bits. What kind of magic do they do with alpha and beta?

Comment: Can you please explain what kind of precise representation of α and β do they assume?

Comment: What precision does who assume, when? Any time you're simulating a physical system, you need to choose a level of precision that's appropriate to the results you're trying to get. For example, if you're calculating shortest routes between cities, you need to decide whether Berlin is 400km from Frankfurt, or 425km or 423km or 423.12347km or...

Comment: @DavidRicherby, maybe that is linked to the fact that sometimes using decomposition size of quantum circuits required for some problem are logarithmic compared to deterministic circuits?

Comment: The application of qubits that they talk about most, is code breaking. For this purpose, α and β should be represented in binary, right? Is it as simple as defining 4 states based on the amplitudes of α and β?

Comment: @Asmani If you're simulating a quantum computer on a classical computer then _everything_ is represented in binary. There's no direct relationship between bits and qubits. They're fundamentally different objects. It's not productive to try to translate between them. It's like saying, "I've heard that cars are faster than horses. So how many horses would I need to go as fast as a car?" That's just not how it works.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Does code breaking require "simulating a quantum computer on a classical computer"? I'm curious to know how α and β are worked with.

Comment: @Asmani If you want to solve stuff on a quantum computer, you build a quantum computer. We're still in the very early stages of doing that so, at the moment, you probably can't build a quantum computer powerful enough to solve your problem. If you want to solve things on a classical computer, you use a classical algorithm. Simulating a quantum algorithm on a classical computer will be slower than just using a classical algorithm, because of the simulation overheads.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Simulating a quantum algorithm on a classical computer will be slower than just using a classical algorithm, because of the simulation overheads. " Not nessecarily. For instance, I wouldn't be surprised if simulating Shor is faster than exhaustive search. What is true is that it is _likely_ that simulating quantum algorithms cannot beat the _best_ classical algorithms due to such overheads, but this doesn't mean that simulating a quantum algorithm can never be the best approach. [See here for more on this idea.](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1353)

Comment: @Discretelizard I think it's pretty clear that I meant "slower than using the most appropriate classical algorithm", rather than "slower than using any possible classical algorithm." If you wanted to get from London to Paris and somebody advised you "take a train", you wouldn't object that not all trains from London go to Paris. Or just consider Grover's algorithm, which _is_ asymptotically faster than any possible classical algorithm.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Perhaps that was clear. My main point is that even when taking the train is fastest we can do, it might be a good idea to look at some rocket we cannot build to see if we can improve our train. This is not really for or against your claim, only tangential. Also, I'm not considering Grover, because classical unordered search has a proven lower bound that is attained and hence simulating Grover cannot beat that.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $ \lvert 0 \rangle $ or $ \lvert 1 \rangle $ as the standard basis of $ \mathbb{C}^2 $. In this sense, a single qubit $ \lvert \psi \rangle $ is nothing more than a unit vector in $ \mathbb{C}^2 $, that is, a linear combination of $ \lvert 0 \rangle $ and $ \lvert 1 \rangle $ with length $1$. Now, a $N$ qubit is an element of $ \mathbb{C}^{2^N} $ since it is defined via the tensor product of single qubits. Maybe that is where (the absurdity) "$N$ qubits correspond to $2^N$ bits" comes from.